# Cannot get group by to work

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have two tables **Employee** and **Office** and **OfficeID** is a foreign key in Employee table. I need to find the number of employees in each office along with the rest of the office details like office city and employee first name. I have written the following query:

```
select o.OfficeID, o.City, o.State, o.Country, o.ZipCode, count(e.EmployeeID) 
from Office o 
inner join Employee e on o.OfficeID = e.OfficeID 
group by o.OfficeID
```

On executing I get the following message -

> Column 'Office.City' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How should I correctly use group by to solve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select o.OfficeID, o.City, o.State, o.Country, o.ZipCode, e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName , officeCnt.cnt
from Employee e
inner join (select OfficeId, count(*) as cnt from Employee group by OfficeId) as officeCnt
        on e.OfficeID = officeCnt.OfficeID;
inner join Office o on e.OfficeID = o.OfficeID
```

You need to count in a subquery where you can apply group by

Comment: thanks. Although I still have to figure out how to show the employee data in a sub grid/ table

Comment: Well this is the only query that shows together the names and the quantity, as you asked for.

Comment: I think that ; after OfficeID is not needed

Answer (score 1):

You either need to include all the non-aggregated columns in the `select` list in the `group by`:

```
select o.OfficeID, o.City, o.State, o.Country, o.ZipCode, 
       count(e.EmployeeID)
from Office o inner join
     Employee e
     on o.OfficeID = e.OfficeID
group by o.OfficeID, o.City, o.State, o.Country, o.ZipCode  ;
```

Or, aggregate the `Employee` separately.  Here is one method:

```
select o.*, e.cnt
from Office o inner join
     (select e.OfficeId, count(*) as cnt
      from Employee e
      group by e.OfficeId
     ) e
     on o.OfficeID = e.OfficeID;
```

This form is handy because you don't have the outer aggregation and can include whatever columns you like from `Office` in the `select`.

Another method uses `cross apply`:

```
select o.*, e.cnt
from Office o inner join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from Employee e
      where o.OfficeID = e.OfficeID
     ) e;
```

This is a bit shorter.